# how to flat array of object into one object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-5

i have a array of object i need to join all into one single object as parent child
for example

```
let array= [
    {
        "Gender": "male",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "small,large,medium"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "male",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "strap",
        "Values": "padded,non-padded"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "pocket",
        "Values": "multiple,zip,buckle"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "small,large,medium"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "sunglasses",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "XL,XXL,XXL"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "sunglasses",
        "Key": "color",
        "Values": "red,black,yellow"
    },
    
]
```

expected output

```
let obj={
    "male": {
        "backpacks": {
            "size": "small,large,medium",
            "strap": "padded,non-padded"
        },
    },
    "female": {
        "backpacks": {
            "size": "small,large,medium",
            "strap": "padded,non-padded"
        },
        "sunglasses": {
            "size": "XL,XXL,XXL",
            "color": "red,black,yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

i tried created a blank object and a for loop then each iteration i added into that object but since it have more level of nest am not able to do
i tried using lodash _.flatten but now working as i expected

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, since you are grouping the items at multiple depths, a [lodash](https://lodash.com/) helper like [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) won't work here, so you'll need to build the object yourself.

You can either [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array, or [manually loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) over it and build your object, whichever you find easier to understand.

I'll use an iterative approach since I'm guessing that'll be easier to understand.

```js
function groupItems(items) {
    let mainGroup = {};
    for (let item of items) {
        const { Gender, Type, Key, Values } = item;

        // If we don't have an object to group by gender yet, create one
        if (!mainGroup[Gender]) {
            mainGroup[Gender] = {};
        }

        // If we don't have an object to group this gender's product yet, create one
        if (!mainGroup[Gender][Type]) {
            mainGroup[Gender][Type] = {};
        }

        // Finally, save the value under the (lowercased) key we received
        mainGroup[Gender][Type][Key.toLowerCase()] = Values;
    }

    return mainGroup;
}

let array = [{"Gender":"male","Type":"backpacks","Key":"size","Values":"small,large,medium"},{"Gender":"male","Type":"backpacks","Key":"strap","Values":"padded,non-padded"},{"Gender":"female","Type":"backpacks","Key":"pocket","Values":"multiple,zip,buckle"},{"Gender":"female","Type":"backpacks","Key":"size","Values":"small,large,medium"},{"Gender":"female","Type":"sunglasses","Key":"size","Values":"XL,XXL,XXL"},{"Gender":"female","Type":"sunglasses","Key":"color","Values":"red,black,yellow"}];

console.log(groupItems(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the array, creating each nested object as needed, then filling in the `Key: Values` elements.

```js
let array= [
    {
        "Gender": "male",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "small,large,medium"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "male",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "strap",
        "Values": "padded,non-padded"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "pocket",
        "Values": "multiple,zip,buckle"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "backpacks",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "small,large,medium"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "sunglasses",
        "Key": "size",
        "Values": "XL,XXL,XXL"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "female",
        "Type": "sunglasses",
        "Key": "color",
        "Values": "red,black,yellow"
    },   
]

let obj = {};

array.forEach(({Gender, Type, Key, Values}) => {
  if (!obj[Gender]) {
    obj[Gender] = {};
  }
  if (!obj[Gender][Type]) {
    obj[Gender][Type] = {};
  }
  obj[Gender][Type][Key] = Values;
});

console.log(obj);
```